Simple Gradio App in Docker Container does not work in Azure Container Registrey für Azure Webapp
I try to create a webapp in Azure, which uses a docker image for a python based Gradio app, which I pushed to my Azure Container Registry before.
I can't access the webapp via the default domain.
I get the following error message in the deployment logs in Azure:
2024-08-18T07:11:52.561Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 for site hello-app-mgl
2024-08-18T07:11:52.598Z ERROR - Container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 for site hello-app-mgl has exited, failing site start
2024-08-18T07:11:52.635Z ERROR - Container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 7860, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.

This is the code of my simple Gradio app:
import gradio as gr


def greet(name):return f"Hello {name}!"

        iface = gr.Interface(fn=greet,
inputs="text",outputs="text").launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860)

This is my dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt ./

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

ENV GRADIO_SERVER_PORT=7860ENV GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=0.0.0.0

EXPOSE 7860

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT ["python3"]

CMD ["./app.py", "--server.port=0000", "--server.port=7860" ]

I created a docker image from this dockerfile:
docker build -t demo-gradio-app .
I tagged and pushed this docker image to my Azure container registry, which worked well.
I created the webapp with the before pushed docker image in the Azure container registry.
I set the environment variable in the setting of the webapp to:
WEBSITES_PORT
7860

I restarted the webapp multiple times.
But, I still get this error in the deployment logs:
2024-08-18T07:11:52.561Z INFO - Initiating warmup request to container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 for site hello-app-mgl

2024-08-18T07:11:52.598Z ERROR - Container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 for site hello-app-mgl has exited, failing site start

2024-08-18T07:11:52.635Z ERROR - Container hello-app-mgl_0_a90587a3 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 7860, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.


Your Dockerfile contains,

CMD ["./app.py", "--server.port=0000", "--server.port=7860" ]

In CMD command where --server.port=0000 should not be there. It should simply specify --server.port=7860.
I used below dockerfile and deployed the gradio app to Azure app service through Azure container registry without any issue.
Dockerfile:
FROM python:3.12
WORKDIR /app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
ENV GRADIO_SERVER_PORT=7860
ENV GRADIO_SERVER_NAME=0.0.0.0
EXPOSE 7860
COPY . .
CMD ["python3", "app.py"]

app. py:
import gradio as gr
def greet(name):
    return f"Hello {name}!"
iface = gr.Interface(fn=greet, inputs="text", outputs="text")
iface.launch(server_name="0.0.0.0", server_port=7860)

For deployment purpose, I created virtual Environment by using below commands.
python -m venv venv 
venv\Scripts\activate

I used below commands to build and run docker image locally.
docker build -t <ImageName> .
docker run -d -p <LocalPort>:<HostPortInDocker>  <ImageName> 

Local Output:

I used the below commands to push the image to the Azure Container registry.
az acr login --n <AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io
docker tag <imageName> <AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io/<imageName>:<tag>
docker push  <AzureContainerRegistryName>.azurecr.io/<imageName>:<tag>

While creating web app I selected Container as publish option and Clicked Next:Container button and App service Pricing Plan is Premium V3 P0V3 as shown below.


Azure App service Output:

